# Common approach to fetch payload and meta data at one go in Backbone.JS?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

What would be an elegant or 'idiomatic' way to fetch JSON data and get a single model and a collection from it, possibly all at one go.

```
{
   meta:  { 
             key: value, 
             key, value    /* This would be the single model */
          }, 
    data: [
            { /* record 1 */ }, 
            { /* record 2 */ }, 
            { /* record 3 */ }, 
            { /* record 4 */ } /* And so on. This would be the collection */
          ]

}
```

Or is the only option I have to fetch the raw JSON and create the model manually from response.meta, and the collection from response.data?

Comment: You can have a parent model to fetch this data, then add a model and collection as its properties from the fetched data in `parse`. This is against the concept though... a model should have it's on end point, and collection should have its.

Comment: @TJ: Can you maybe provide a simple expample or pseudo code of how you'd fetch the data and transform it into a model and a collection. It seems to be against the concept, but there are thousands of APIs that return payload data and meta data, and fetching those with two requests isn't the solution either, i'd say. That's why I thought there must be a common solution to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always override the `parse` method, for example:

```
parse: function(response){
      return response['data'];
}
```

Ref: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse
This will create the model using the attributes within "data".

you are invited to see a dummy example iv'e just created:

http://jsfiddle.net/5pjha/2890/